# Graph QL query for all the comments on PR of given author

Tags: graphql, github-api

I was able to come up with this:

```
{
  repository(owner: "hawkular", name: "hawkular.github.io") {
    pullRequest(number: 237) {
      comments(first: 10) {
        nodes {
          body
          author {
            login
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which returns all the comments on the given PR:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequest": {
        "comments": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "body": "PR was auto-deployed here: http://209.132.178.114:10237 and it will be available for 4 days.\n",
              "author": {
                "login": "hawkular-website-bot"
              }
            },
            {
              "body": "Any ETA for this blog post to be finished/published ?",
              "author": {
                "login": "theute"
              }
            },
            {
              "body": "After PR696 in hawkular-metrics I will continue.. helps me to create something repetable",
              "author": {
                "login": "burmanm"
              }
            },
            {
              "body": "PR was auto-deployed here: http://209.132.178.114:10237 and it will be available for 4 days.",
              "author": {
                "login": "hawkular-website-bot"
              }
            },
            {
              "body": "The article cites `CompressionData` job, but it should be `CompressData`.",
              "author": {
                "login": "jsanda"
              }
            },
            {
              "body": "Is this PR active ? Severla months without activity.",
              "author": {
                "login": "lucasponce"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

however I am interested only in those written by `hawkular-website-bot`. Is there a way to specify the author in Git Hub Graph QL api?

Answer (score 1):

There is no filter criterion on the author in type `PullRequestConnection`. So you can't filter pull requests based on the author. But you can use search query feature like

```
{
  search(query: "repo: hawkular/hawkular.github.io is:pr is:open author:hawkular-website-bot", last:10, type:ISSUE){
    edges{
      node{
        ... on PullRequest{
          body
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For details see [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests)